# "nohup cat" -- write the complete content to the log file rather to concatenate file

Tags: bash, io-redirection, cat, nohup

I used the below command

```
nohup cat fastp-filtered/OZBenth*_R1.fastp.fq.gz > fastp-filtered-merged4racon/merge_R1.fq.gz > merge_R1.out.log 2>&1 &
```

but unfortunately, the output went to `merge_R1.out.log` and not to `merge_R1.fq.gz`.

What did I miss?

Comment: What do you expect from `cat fastp-filtered/OZBenth*_R1.fastp.fq.gz > fastp-filtered-merged4racon/merge_R1.fq.gz` This will be mess from compressed files and with high probability will not be able to decompress

Comment: @RomeoNinov No it wouldn't. The concatenated file, when uncompressed, would be concatenation of the uncompressed files.  This is likely what is intended and it will work.

Comment: `cat <(tar zcf - a) <(tar zcf - b) | tar -ztf -` shows `a`.

Comment: @WeijunZhou Yes, because two concatenated `tar` archives don't make much sense.  Try `cat <( gzip -cf <<<"HELLO" ) <( gzip -cf <<<"WORLD" ) | gzip -dc` instead.  The result would be the same as `cat <( echo HELLO ) <( echo WORLD )`

Comment: @WeijunZhou What the user is dealing with here is a collection compressed text files containing genomic "fastq" sequence data.  They are merging the compressed files together and will later used the merged file for something. There will be no issues with this.

Comment: Related: [How to combine gunzipped fastq files?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/158941)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redirections are processed in a left-to-right fashion.

When executing a command like

```
somecommand >f1 >f2 >f3
```

the shell will first create or truncate (empty) the file `f1`, then `f2` and lastly `f3`.  Then it starts `somecommand` with its standard output connected to `f3`.

To save the output of a command to multiple files, you would have to duplicate the data for each output file.  This is easiest done with `tee`:

```
somecommand | tee f1 f2 >f3
```

This sends the output of `somecommand` to `tee` which duplicates it into the two files `f1` and `f2`.  The `tee` utility also produces the same data on its own standard output, and in the command above we simply redirect this into `f3`.

In your case, you would use

```
nohup cat fastp-filtered/OZBenth*_R1.fastp.fq.gz 2>&1 |
tee fastp-filtered-merged4racon/merge_R1.fq.gz >merge_R1.out.log &
```

The `2>&1` makes the error stream from `cat` be sent to `tee` as well (this may not be wanted as any errors would corrupt the resulting archive).

`tee` truncates its output files, just like `>` would do.  Use `tee` with its `-a` option to append data to an output file.

---

It's unlikely that you actually meant for all output from `cat` to be written to two files though, so assuming that you want to save the *errors* to the log file and the concatenated archives to the output file, you would instead do

```
nohup cat fastp-filtered/OZBenth*_R1.fastp.fq.gz \
    >fastp-filtered-merged4racon/merge_R1.fq.gz \
    2>merge_R1.out.log &
```

without the need for using `tee` at all.

Comment: Conceptually correct, but I don't think this is what the OP is asking for.

Comment: @WeijunZhou This was addressed in the second half of the answer, after the divider, as a result of your comment.